# NODEJS: Return array of arrays from dialog openDirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, electron

**I am working in a electron desktop app, and what I need to do is:**

1. Open a directory using 'dialog.showOpenDialog'.
2. Filter the files by their extension.
3. Read filtered files (they have no header).
4. Parse them into columns and return only columns 4 and 6 (coordinates).
5. Return an array of arrays of all the files (Output example at the end).

**With my little knowledge in js, this is my code so far, I'm stuck at point 4:**

```
document.getElementById('btn-readfile').addEventListener('click', () => {

    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openDirectory']
    }).then(function(response) {
        if (!response.canceled) {
            dirname = response.filePaths[0] + '\\'
            var fs = require('fs');
            var path = require('path');

            function readFiles(dirname, onFileContent, onError) {
                fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, files) {
                    if (err) {
                        onError(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    filesList = files.filter(function(e) {
                        return path.extname(e).toLowerCase() === '.txt' // ==> Filter files by extension
                    });
                    filesList.forEach(function(filesList) {
                        fs.readFile(dirname + filesList, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
                            if (err) {
                                onError(err);
                                return;
                            }

                            onFileContent(filesList, content);

                        });
                    });
                });
            }
            var data = {};
            readFiles(dirname, function(filesList, content) {
                data[filesList] = content;
                console.log(data[filesList]);
            }, function(err) {
                throw err;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("no file selected");
        }
    });
}, false);
```

**Raw file:**

```
-1  2021-01-20  08:11:19    43.30981408167  N   13.73270596167  E   1.08    M   4
-1  2021-01-20  08:11:20    43.30981406000  N   13.73270596333  E   1.07    M   4
-1  2021-01-20  08:11:21    43.30981403667  N   13.73270598333  E   1.07    M   4
-1  2021-01-20  08:11:22    43.30981403833  N   13.73270598500  E   1.07    M   4
1   2021-01-20  08:11:23    43.30981406333  N   13.73270597333  E   1.07    M   4
2   2021-01-20  08:11:24    43.30981404833  N   13.73270598167  E   1.07    M   4
3   2021-01-20  08:11:25    43.30981459167  N   13.73270569667  E   1.08    M   4
9   2021-01-20  08:11:26    43.30981820000  N   13.73270345667  E   1.07    M   4
```

**Desired Output:** an array of arrays, where every array represent columns 4 and 6 from every file in the folder.

```
var latlng = [
                [
                    [ 45.64172279, 10.19579398],
                    [ 45.64193714, 10.1958776],
                    [ 45.64220345, 10.19598908],
                    [ 45.6423983, 10.19606341],
                    [ 45.6429504, 10.19632354],
                    [ 45.64329464, 10.19658367],
                    [ 45.64341805, 10.19758703]
                ],
                [
                    [ 45.64339856, 10.19838601],
                    [ 45.64313876, 10.1987855],
                    [ 45.64244377, 10.19869259],
                    [ 45.6418527, 10.19879479],
                    [ 45.6415669, 10.19715967],
                    [ 45.64170331, 10.19648147],
                    [ 45.64189167, 10.19615631]
                ]
            ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't cram everything into the event handler, that's not reusable and has horrible maintainability. Make functions that take over the fundamental parts of your task.

First, top-level dependencies go to the top.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
```

A function that reads a directory and returns a promise for an array of filenames:

```
function getFilesAsync(dirname) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, files) {
            if (err) reject(err); else resolve(files);
        });
    });
}
```

A function that takes a filename and an optional encoding, and returns a promise for the file content:

```
function getFileContentAsync(filename, encoding) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filename, {encoding: encoding}, function (err, content) {
            if (err) reject (err); else resolve(content);
        });
    });
}
```

A function that takes a block of text and splits it into rows and columns at certain positions (since your data uses fixed-width columns):

```
function splitFixedColumnData(text, positions) {
    return text.split('\n').map(line => 
        positions.concat(line.length).map( (pos, i) => 
            line.substring(positions[i-1] || 0, pos).trim() // from the previous to the current column pos
        )
    );
}
```

And a function that picks out certain elements from an array, so you can pick the columns you want to work with from the larger set of columns the previous function returns:

```
function pluckArray(arr, indexes) {
    return arr.reduce((result, v, i) => {
        if (indexes.includes(i)) result.push(v);
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```

And with all these defined, we can combine them to do something useful:

```
document.getElementById('btn-readfile').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    let dlg = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openDirectory']
    });
    if (dlg.canceled) {
        console.log("no file selected");
        return;
    }

    try {
        let txtFiles = (await getFilesAsync(root))
            .filter(fn => path.extname(fn).toLowerCase() === '.txx')
            .map(fn => path.join(root, fn));
        let pendingContents = txtFiles.map(fn => getFileContentAsync(fn, 'utf-8'));
        let contents = await Promise.all(pendingContents);
        let columnData = contents.map(text => splitFixedColumnData(text, [4, 16, 28, 44, 48, 64, 68, 76, 80]));
        let latlng = columnData.map(rows => rows.map(row => pluckArray(row, [3, 5])));

        for (let i = 0; i < txtFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(txtFiles[i], latlng[i]);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is great, and very usefull to understand how should I do it in the correct way. I will try it right know!

Comment: I get: ".filter" is not a function and also ".map" is not a function. Do you know why this could be? thanks

Comment: @SantiagoLuquez Yes, that's missing parentheses. Hang on.

Comment: Now I get this: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "options" argument must be one of type string or object. Could be something of the encoding?

Comment: @Santiago Sorry for that, I should have tested my code better, there were still a few bloopers in there. I've redone my answer. I can only recommend to *not* just copy and paste my code. Try out each function individually, see what it does. Comment out lines, output intermediary results. See what's going on step by step. Read documentation about keywords or patterns you don't know. Write functions to experiment with stuff you don't fully understand, etc. This is not meant to be a drop-in replacement for your code, but as an exercise.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for the help, it is a big help and I sure it will work! I will read and try one function at a time.